# cake php default routing not work

Tags: cakephp, routes

I want to define master routing for cakephp somthing like this.

```
Router::connect('/:lang/:plugins/:controller/:action/*', array('lang' => 'eng', 'controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index', 'plugin' => null), array('lang' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

but default not works. when i type these errors disappear:

```
/           Error: Controller could not be found.
/eng        Error: EngController could not be found.
/eng/pages  Error: EngController could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

What the route errors are saying is that the controller that you're asking it to use doesn't exist. I'm assuming you're using CakePHP 2, so make sure your controller filename is like this:

`EngController.php`

And inside that controller file it is similar to this:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Eng Controller
 *
 */
class EngController extends AppController {

/**
 * Scaffold
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
    public $scaffold;

}
```

**EDIT:**
I had another look at the route, and you have `'lang' => 'eng'` at the start of the route. The errors you're getting are from the route thinking that `eng` is a controller. Remove this section altogether and it should fix it.

Comment: My problem is for routing not or controller

Comment: Your routes can't find the controller. I can't see anything wrong with your route, so I would check your controllers.